# Find $a,b$ in $3a^2-b^2=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Find all integer solution of the equation $3a^2-b^2=1$.
It is my problem.I seemed easy but I have no way to do this.

Comment: Is the right-hand side 0 (as in the title) or 1 (as in the body of the question)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $$3a^2-b^2 =1 \implies b^2 +1=3a^2 \implies b^2 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$$
This is a contradiction, as no square can be $-1$ modulo $3$, as shown through $$(3k)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$$$(3k \pm 1)^2 \equiv 3(3k^2 \pm 2k )+ 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$

Answer (score 0):

since
$$3a^2=b^2+1$$
use well know
$$b^2+1\equiv1, 2\pmod 4$$
and 
$$3a^2\equiv 0,3 \pmod 4$$